# I want to style Opencart checkout grand total

Tags: php, css, opencart

I am trying to style my Opencart theme, but I have a problem.

I want to style the grand total result on the checkout page. The problem is I can't style only the grand total result because automatic changes the Sub-total style.

For example I want to make the grand total result **BOLD**

The code is this:

```
 <tfoot>
  <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="price"><b><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</b></td>
    <td colspan="2" class="grandtotal-style-css"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</tfoot>
```

I found this but is for old Opencart and is not working.

Link is here (opencart.com)
http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1986#p9366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each type of totals row has a unique code (total, sub_total, shipping etc.), so personally, I would change it to something like this:

```
<tfoot>

  <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>

  <tr>

    <td colspan="2" class="price"><b><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</b></td>
    <td colspan="2" class="totals-<?php echo $total['code']; ?>"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>

  </tr>

  <?php } ?>

</tfoot>
```

Then change your css class from `.grandtotal-style-css` to `.totals-total`

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the `:last-of-type` pseudo-element?

```
.grandtotal-style-css:last-of-type {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for the `code` of the totals and add styles only for the `total` (or `grandtotal`?) one:

```
  <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
  <tr>
    <?php if ($total['code'] == 'total') { /* change for 'grandtotal' if needed */ ?>
    <td colspan="2" class="price"><b><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</b></td>
    <td colspan="2" class="grandtotal-style-css"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
    <?php } else {
    <td colspan="2" class="price"><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
```